# Can we extract pdf pages using lua scripts

Tags: pdf, lua

Our application is receiving PDF file based on 150 pages from business line, I want to extract pages from this pdf file using lua scripts.

Any body share his experience.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a Lua wrapper calling something like [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this. As long as you write a Lua module that can read PDF files.

There are [some](http://luahpdf.luaforge.net/) Lua modules for writing PDFs, but none for reading them. No public ones, at any rate. You may want to switch to Python for this, as there are quite a few Python modules for dealing with PDFs.